# How to use Gradle and regex to parse XML + comments and save to a new file

Tags: xml, groovy

If I have an XML file in the shape below and want to parse this with Regex in Groovy how can I do this in a very simple manner and create a new file from it? There is a reason why I would like to use regex instead of manipulating the DOM. I need to have the comments to go to the new file.

I don't want to specify which elements to delete in the XML file either, it could be multiple more elements that could be added that I don't know of. So it's should be: remove everything except the root element and the tasks element and it's children and comments inside.

**Initial file:**

```
<root attribute1="attribute">
    <tests>
        <test>Test 1</test>
        <test>Test 2</test>
    </tests>
    <tasks>
        <!--
        <task name="task one" >
            Some task that is commented
        </task>
        -->

        <task name="task one" >
            Some text
        </task>
    </tasks>
</root>
```

**New file:**

```
<root attribute1="attribute">
    <tasks>
        <!--
        <task name="task one" >
            Some task that is commented
        </task>
        -->

        <task name="task one" >
            Some text
        </task>
    </tasks>
</root>
```

**This is how far I got with the Gradle function:**

```
def extractXml() {
    def input = new File("initial_file.xml")
    
    if (input.exists()) {
        def doc = DOMBuilder.parse(new StringReader(input.text))
        def rootElement = doc.documentElement

        use(DOMCategory) {
            String xmlEventContent = rootElement as String
            new File("new_file.xml").write(xmlEventContent)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is closer to what you want?

```
def extractXml() {
    def input = new File("initial_file.xml")
    
    if (input.exists()) {
        def doc = DOMBuilder.parse(new StringReader(input.text)).documentElement
        use(DOMCategory) {
            doc.each {
                if (it.nodeName != 'tasks' && it.nodeName != '#text') {
                    doc.removeChild(it)
                }
            }
            String xmlEventContent = doc as String
            new File("new_file.xml").write(xmlEventContent)
        }
    }
}
```

Anything to avoid using regex